# Low-quality paper or no paper - which is better for an undergraduate in PhD admission?

Tags: phd, publications, research-undergraduate

As everybody knows, research experience helps in one undergraduate's admission to a PhD program. It would be even better, if the undergraduate has a publication out of his or her research experience.

However, for a full-time undergraduate, it is quite difficult to devote too much time to research since one still has the school work to deal with. *(Maintaining a high GPA is also important, isn't it?)* Given the time limitation by this or other reasons, the **undergraduate** may face the following dilemma.

The **quality** of work is **low**, but the undergraduate has **no time to improve it**.

**Should the undergraduate publish it to a random and low-tier conference to at least have a publication?**

OR

**Should he or she just make it a technical report instead of publishing it?**

In other words, during the PhD admission, **how do the admission committees or professors view a low-quality conference paper?** Do they take it as an advantage in the sense that most of the undergraduates have none. Or do they start suspecting the student's research potentials? **Does a low-quality "1" win a "0" in this case?**

FYI, the field of interest is EECS, but any generic comments are also very much appreciated!

Comment: Making it a technical report _is_ publishing it.

Comment: IMHO a technical report is the best option, because it could be expanded or improved and become part of a "real" publication. I would consider doing that with a low-tier conference as salami publishing, even if a technical report is publishing (as @JeffE points) I see a difference in both. But that may be just me.

Comment: @JeffE Sorry for the confusion. What I mean by that is to make it non-public report that logs what I have done.

Comment: what do you mean by: "The quality of work is low"?

Comment: @Trylks  Sorry for the confusion caused! I mean the experimental data fail to show that the result is promising.

Comment: Sound and disappointing conclusions are not bad conclusions. Look at Gödel. Research is not about what is good, but about what is true.

Comment: @Trylks But it turns that my method does not even perform as well as a very naive one.. it is really disappointing. Then is it still worth it?

Comment: IMHO yes, if someone finds that homeopathy performs even worse than the placebo effect, would you consider that publishing that is important?

Comment: See this related question of mine asked from the other side of the table http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/value-of-light-to-none-peer-reviewed-pay-to-publish-articles

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Thanks for the link, It is really related. So the professors do have doubt about this kind of thing. I guess I am gradually reaching the conclusion that a bad 1 is actually worse than 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the quality of the work is low, the student should neither publish it in a lower tier conference nor publish it as a technical report.  They should either make the time to improve it or toss it in the trash.  A **bad** publication, no matter what venue it's published in, is worse than no publication at all.

Similarly, a "publication" listed in a CV or described in a statement of purpose that isn't retrievable via google (unlike most technical reports, which *are* googlable) is also worse than no publication at all, because we can't tell if the applicant is lying.  (Sadly, some applicants are lying.)

Comment: I'm not sure we have the same concept of a "bad" publication. For me a bad publication is not wrong, it's simply not very relevant, maybe relatively obvious, maybe a small improvement over the state of the art. If it is well written and correct, I don't see how could that be worse than no-publication. Could you elaborate that?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your opinion on this issue is is really valuable, because 1. same field 2. you must be in the phd admission committee. I originally thought 1 was better than 0, since most of the undergrads have non.

Comment: @Trylks What you're describing doesn't fit the OP's description "The quality of the work is low...".

Comment: I'm not sure we have the same concept of quality. Asked for clarification ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a different opinion:

I think you should push it forward for publication in a national conference, not international  (because quality is low)

The weightage for this will definitely be less, But it leaves a different impression if you have some published work.