# Will the publications on Open Acess journal (like Hindawi) harm the PhD application to economics or finance departments in USA (or MPhil in UK)?

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-admissions, journals, application

How will the departments view the PhD, PostDoc, and AP applicants with SJR tier Q3(4) publications and/or publications on open access journals?

Personally I believe that at the specialization level of Postdoc and AP, committees are looking after publications on specific good journals rather the name of the publisher. But at PhD level I am not sure what will happen. I doubt that the super busy faculties in top departments will bother reading the applicant's publications in detail just because s/he paid $100 application fee.

Is a publication on a Springer journal (but with SJR tier Q3) looks better than an open access journal with tier Q2?

We often do not have time to go through an article in detail. In academia, will you pay more attention to articles published by prestigious publishers (Elsevier, Springer, Sage, academic societies, Etc.), provided that all the other credentials (affiliations, ranks, names) of a paper are the same?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about mathematics (given your profile) then the answers will differ depending on whether you are talking about PhD applications, PostDoc applications, or Assistant Professor applications. It will also depend slightly on which country you are applying to, since some countries operate Research Assessment exercises where "having papers in esteemed journals" matters

Comment: @YemonChoi economics or finance departments in USA

Comment: When faced with a similar situation, it was hard for me to evaluate the work: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7908/929

Comment: @StrongBad Some pay-to-publish venues are more selective than others. For example Hindawi's acceptance rate is 7%, much lower than the "big five".

Comment: I find it hard to imagine _anyone_ thinking better of a paper just because people have to pay to read it.